# Appwarp - Connection Resiliency

Tags: c#, network-programming, windows-phone, multiplayer, appwarp

I'm currently implementing connection resiliency for a windows phone game following this documentation: [Appwarp Connection Resiliency](http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/connection-resiliency/).

I can't seem to access the RecoverConnection API or any of the Connect Event Result Codes related to Connection Resiliency (SUCCESS_RECOVERED, CONNECTION_ERROR_RECOVERABLE, etc) in the ConnectionRequestListener in my project.

Looking at the AppWarp_WP7_SDK.dll in my project it doesnt seem to contain these API calls. I'm using the .dll downloaded from [Appwarp Windows SDK](http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/windows-game-developers-home/#Samples-Video). Anyone know has the .dll changed? Have they been removed from the latest version?

Cheers,
xDev

Answer (score 1):

> Please take our latest dll from below link
>
> https://github.com/shephertz/AppWarp_WP7_SDK_DLL
>
> We have also one sample game "Catapult War" in which we have implemented Connection Resiliency feature.Find it from below link
>
> https://github.com/rahulpshephertz/CatapultWar
>
> At the time of initialization don't forget to set recovery allowance.
>     WarpClient.setRecoveryAllowance(60);